# Right way to share dynamic files between services in docker compose

Tags: django, reactjs, docker, docker-compose, docker-image

I have the following docker-compose file. I'd like to share the static files from the `react` service with the `nginx` and `web` services

```
version: '3.6'

services:

  web:
    image: shahrukh/learnup:web
    networks:
      - main
    command: >
      sh -c "python manage.py collectstatic --no-input
      && gunicorn learnup.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 --reload"
    volumes:
      - static_cdn:/var/www/learnup/static_cdn
    depends_on:
      - react
  
  react:
    image: shahrukh/learnup:react
    volumes: 
      - static_cdn:/app/Learnup-Frontend/learnup/export-build/static

  nginx:
    image: shahrukh/learnup:nginx
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 80:80
    command: nginx -g 'daemon off;'
    volumes:
      - static_cdn:/var/www/static
    networks:
      - main
    depends_on:
      - web
      - react

networks:
  main:

volumes: 
  static_cdn:
```

For this, I created a named volume `static_cdn` on which the following steps would happen

1. The build folder for my react app from the `react` service will be
   mounted here
2. Static data from django's collectstatic command will be copied here
3. This is shared with `nginx` which will serve it.

Here's the problem I am facing.

**On updating my `react` container image with the latest build the volume `static_cdn` doesn't have the latest static files, as the volume isn't recreated after I use `docker-compose up -d`**

So my question is **What is the best way to share files between services in this scenario?** So that it takes care of the updates.

Please note that I am aware of the solution to first use `docker-compose down -v` to stop & remove volumes and then do `docker-compose up -d`. But it results in downtime which I don't want on the production.

Also doing `docker-compose pull react` to pull the latest image of `react` and then doing `docker-compose -d` didn't work because the volume doesn't update. Docker compose doesn't provide any option as of now to force recreate volumes on startup. Neither can I use `docker volume rm ...` as the volumes are in use.

Also, note that I can create the react build files at the time of startup instead of making it a part of the image which will solve the issue. But I can't do it as I am running the application on a system with limited resource and `npm run build` just crashes on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically if you're building a React application, you'll want to compile it to static files to deploy it.  You'll use a tool like Webpack that produces a set of built HTML, Javascript, and CSS files, and then you can directly serve those using Nginx.  If you're using a starter kit like Create React App, you can usually run something like

```
npm run build
```

and it will create a `dist` directory with the built files.

Since you already have an Nginx container, the first thing this means is that you don't need a separate React container; you can just serve the compiled files out of the Nginx container.  Also, the backend container probably doesn't need direct access to the built front-end code, it just needs to get served up from the Nginx proxy.

That means you can build an Nginx proxy image, with the built React application, in a single multi-stage build.  That Dockerfile would look more or less like:

```sh
FROM node:lts AS react
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json .
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build

FROM nginx
COPY --from=react /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY default.conf.template /etc/nginx/templates/
# Base image includes a useful CMD
```

In the Compose setup you do not need a dedicated React container, as previously discussed; you do not need volumes, since you're building the application into static files already; you don't need to restate things like `command:` that are already declared in your images; and you can use the `default` network that Compose provides for you.  This would give you a much-simplified `docker-compose.yml` file:

```yaml
version: '3.6'
services:
  web:
    build: ./backend
    image: shahrukh/learnup-web:latest

  nginx:
    build: ./frontend
    image: shahrukh/learnup-nginx:latest
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 80:80
    depends_on:
      - web
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this looks much cleaner. I'll try this approach and I'll update here. But I'll need a volume as there'll be static files copied via django collectstatic command.

Comment: You could probably build that into the multi-stage build I describe here too, assuming it doesn't depend on the database.

Comment: Using multi stage build has greatly optimized my Dockerfile. However I'm stuck at one place. I'm using gunicorn with nginx. In my multi stage build I'll have to run nginx as well as gunicorn. How to achieve that? Can you please update it in the answer so that anyone looking for a solution might be benefited.

Answer (score 1):

**You seems to want to use docker-compose for production.**

docker-compose is not meant for production use. it will not for example attempt to restart a failed container. It will also destroy container before recreating them, causing downtime. Please consider using docker-swarm (easier) or kubernetes (the industry de-facto standard).

These tool know how to perform the updates, manage persistent volume, deal with hardware failures and so on.

**Dealing with your static files in production**

If really your static content is code, basically a dev change, that you may want to revert in case of error and that you version with something like git, then create a container with it and version it.

When you publish a new version & notify your prod cluster, it will automatically update all your production node with a sane update strategy. if you discover there an issue with the new version, you can just rollback.

If it is really dynamic, you'll likely want another driver for your volume, like mapping to a network file system.

Anyway take a look as how docker-swarm & kubernetes work, it will clarify what is good for prod env.

**Working locally**

Locally, it is completely acceptable to use the -v option to remove the container and have a few seconds of downtime.

Comment: I'm new to using containers for deployment. I read at few places including dockers documentation that docker compose is suitable for production l, but this is my first time trying it. I'll have a look at kubernetes but for the time being I need a solution with compose. Versioning my images would be good idea, but I don't know how it'll solve my issue with volumes. If you can help me with few docs on how to use network fs  to solve this, it'll be really helpful. Thanks for your suggestion with local development.

Comment: Compose is not made for production, it support only single node deployment, basically if you don't put a load balencer you manage yourself in front + monitoring, if your node fail, compose will do absolutely nothing to get it back up.

Comment: If you don't have your application distributed on multiple nodes, there no way it will stay available with a good SLA. At some point you'll need to eventually reboot the machine, at some point a bug in your app will freeze the process, at some point the hardware will fail.

Comment: Where I work we consider that the minimum number of nodes to serve an application is 3: 1 node to serve the traffic, 1 node for redundancy, 1 node that may be in maintenance. A few years back, for a hardware load balencer, we had 2 in //, we unplugged 1 for the maintenance like for half an hour and it is at that moment that the other one failed... We destroyed our SLA, we paid millions in compensations to our clients and our issue made the news on TV.

Comment: You have docker-compose, so you have docker. So you have docker swarm, it is just 1 command line away (https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/swarm-mode/). Follow a tutorial like this one until the end and you'll see how you'll be able to update to new container version without any dowtime... And if you now put your file in versionned container, you'll see how you'll be able to update your website without downtime at all.